# IC Thermal shutdown recovery time

Tags: temperature, rs485, junction

Many RS485 transceiver chips have a thermal shutdown when the junction exceeds 150C. Typically they switch back on once the junction temperature drops 15 degrees.

How long does that typically take?

Since the power is dropping to near zero, and junction to case thermal resistance is typically 50C/watt, does that mean it can potentially drop temp very quickly and recover within microseconds?

Comment: In order to answer, we'd need to know what chip you're talking about specifically, though I suspect it depends on thermal capacitance, which isn't likely to be listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not microseconds - there will be some temperature hysteresis and some heat capacity. Probably more the order of a second than microseconds.